# LG Optimus L70 Google Apps Gone

Tags: google-play-store, sync, google-account

I dropped my phone and the battery fell out. When I put it in and turned on my phone, all my Google apps were gone! Play Store, Chrome, etc.

My accounts won't sync; I get this play services error and when I hold the notification and touch "app info", Accounts Sync comes up. I checked my Google accounts in Settings and they're all not syncing due to some error.

I am rooted, by the way.

Comment: Before attempting to do anything, make yourself a favor. Take a custom recovery (for example, TWRP) and perform a Nandroid backup. Should things require a factory reset, you'll be able to restore your apps' data, via Titanium Backup. Now, let's get to business. Did you try the easy solution - downloading a Gapps package?

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried a factory reset? I fear it could be the only way to solve the issue, hope you enabled the Google backup feature so that it could restore your apps and data as soon as you login in the next setup process.

If this doesn't work, your internal memory hardware could be seriously damaged and the only solution would be official repair, unfortunately!

Comment: About the section dealing with hardware damage: if it were a HW issue, how come *only all the Google apps* disappeared but not any other user or system app?

Comment: doesn't mean nothing but that only a portion of the memory could be damaged.. BTW obviously those are only theories, until the user tries something there's no way to exclude anything!